# how to get favicon.ico work on tornado

Tags: python-3.x, tornado

the tornado server didn't do the favicon.ico by default,so i always get the info like these

```
[W 130626 10:38:16 web:1514] 404 GET /favicon.ico (192.168.1.57) 0.57ms
```

i use the web.staticfilehandler in various way include the source's example,and couldn't get it work, i got things work like this below.

```
handlers = [
    (r'/favicon.ico', tornado.web.StaticFileHandler,dict(url='/static/favicon.ico',permanent=False)),
    (r'/static/(.*)', tornado.web.StaticFileHandler, {"path": "plserver"}),
 ]
```

i felt so dump,i have to redirect it and couldn't sure it will work on web page in real world.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

And I changed it to this one, this time I've got what I want

```
handlers = [
    (r'/(favicon.ico)', tornado.web.StaticFileHandler, {"path": ""}),
 ]
```

*I got the answer while i wrote the post.*

Answer (score 3):

I put the favicon.ico in the `.\static\`, and add following code to html.

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ static_url('favicon.ico') }}">
```

it would be generated like this:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/static/favicon.ico?v=bb3f1">
```

That's all.