# python-tornado dont match "/favicon.ico"

Tags: python, tornado

question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17311084/how-to-get-favicon-ico-work-on-tornado) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10165665/using-tornado-how-do-i-serve-static-files-and-serve-a-favicon-ico-from-a-differ) do not help :(

I'm trying to handler "/favicon.ico" but it doesn't work as expected.It's wired...

My handler looks like:

```
handlers = [ 
    (r'^/$', RootHandler),    # this works fine
    (r'^/favicon\.ico$', IconHandler),
    # other handlers
]
```

My `IconHandler` looks like:

```
class IconHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.set_header("Content-Type", "image/vnd.microsoft.icon")
        with open(icon_path, 'rb') as f:
            self.write(f.read())
        return self.flush()
```

But `http://127.0.0.1:8000/favicon.ico` gives me a 404 error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tyler/.pyenv/versions/3.4.2/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1334, in _execute
    result = yield result
  File "/home/tyler/.pyenv/versions/3.4.2/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 628, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/home/tyler/.pyenv/versions/3.4.2/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tornado/concurrent.py", line 109, in result
    raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_exc_info
  File "/home/tyler/.pyenv/versions/3.4.2/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 175, in wrapper
    yielded = next(result)
  File "/home/tyler/.pyenv/versions/3.4.2/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 2110, in get
    self.root, absolute_path)
  File "/home/tyler/.pyenv/versions/3.4.2/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 2286, in validate_absolute_path
    raise HTTPError(404)
tornado.web.HTTPError: HTTP 404: Not Found
```

So I changed the url match pattern and did some tests:

```
handler pattern        | url                                   | status
-----------------------|---------------------------------------|--------
r'^/favicon\.ico$'     | http://127.0.0.1:8000/favicon.ico     | 404Error
r'/favicon\.ico'       | http://127.0.0.1:8000/favicon.ico     | 404Error
r'/favicon.ico'        | http://127.0.0.1:8000/favicon.ico     | 404Error
r'^/sub/favicon\.ico$' | http://127.0.0.1:8000/sub/favicon.ico | Works!
r'/sub/favicon\.ico'   | http://127.0.0.1:8000/sub/favicon.ico | Works!
r'/sub/favicon.ico'    | http://127.0.0.1:8000/sub/favicon.ico | Works!
```

PLEASE HELP. I can not understand :(

python: 3.4.2

tornado: 4.0.2

Ubuntu: 14.10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you have `static_path` field in your app settings. And what happens in your case is this:

> You can serve static files by sending the static_path setting as a
>   keyword argument.

And:

> note that a StaticFileHandler can be installed automatically with the
>   static_path setting

**Favicon pattern is automatically inserted** to the handlers patterns list when you have `static_path` setting configured. And those automatic static patterns have higher priority than all your own patterns.

This your traceback is proof:

```
  File "/home/tyler/.pyenv/versions/3.4.2/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 2286, in validate_absolute_path
    raise HTTPError(404)
```

So, I suggest you remove `static_path` from your app settings, and add your own `/static` pattern like this

```
(r"/static/(.*)", web.StaticFileHandler, {"path": my_path}),
```

Comment: YEAH that works!. And another way is to put the "favicon.ico" directly under the `static_path` then tornado will auto handle it. Thx you saved my day :)